# How to plot relative proportions over time in R

Tags: r, plot

For my research I am trying to create a similar graph based around this graph I found in a piece of literature:

[image: Graph from Golder & Hubermann (2005)]

My experiment involved the genre-tagging of 10 different songs. I saved the tags (the words people used to describe seperately).
The x-asis should represent all the participants that took part in chronological order. The y-axis should represent how often a word is used in a tag. Consider this sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(tagid= numeric(0), participantid = numeric(0), tag = character(0))
newRow <-data.frame(tagid=1, participantid=1, tag = "triphop")
df <-rbind(df,newRow)
newRow <-data.frame(tagid=2, participantid=1, tag = "electronic")
df <-rbind(df,newRow)
newRow <-data.frame(tagid=3, participantid=2, tag = "mellow")
df <-rbind(df,newRow)
newRow <-data.frame(tagid=4, participantid=2, tag = "electronic")
df <-rbind(df,newRow)
newRow <-data.frame(tagid=5, participantid=3, tag = "electronic")
df <-rbind(df,newRow)
```

Tagid 1 and 2 belong to the same participant and should have the same x coordinate. 3 and 4 belong to participant 2 and tagid 5 belongs to participant 3.

For this dataset I'd like to plot a graph like this (excuse the drawing):

[image: The graph I'd like to be able to plot in R]

The y-axis represents the percentage of participants that have used a specific word to describe this music piece. As 'electronic' is used by all three participants it stays at 100%. 'Triphop' was used by participant 1, but not by participant 2 and 3, decreasing from 100%, to 50%, to 33% at participant 3.

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is the problem you are having when trying to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your y-axis in your desired plot.

Comment: You've obviously went to some effort to describe your problem. Thx. However it is usually simpler fo rpeople to understand when you just show the first few lines of your data e.g. `head(mydata)`

Comment: @MrFlick, the y-axis represents the percentage of taggers that have used a specific line. As electronic is used by all three participants, it's present in 100% of the tags.

Comment: @slayernoah, I have had difficulty understanding how to formulate my problem, and thus have not been able to try something.. A firm finger in the right direction that points me to some key concepts might be a good start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is a bit messy, but probably you want something like this ? You need to complete the dataframe so each `participantid` has rows for all three tag levels. Then, with the cumulative sum of the tag levels and the cumulative sum of participants, you can get the proportion.

```
df %>%  
  group_by(participantid, tag) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  complete(tag, nesting(participantid), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  group_by(tag) %>% 
  mutate(absolute = cumsum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:3, each = length(levels(tag)))) %>%
  mutate(proportion = ifelse(absolute / id != 0, absolute / id, NA)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = participantid, y = proportion, color = tag)) + geom_line(lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I'm going to try and replicate this tomorrow morning,   thanks this looks a lot like what I need!

Comment: Thanks erocoar, this graph is plotting exactly what I wanted.  


I have a follow-up question to this answer. My true dataset does not start with participant_id 1, but with 3. A total of 93 participants are considered, id's ranging from 3 to 347.   


![Current plot!](https://imgur.com/a/IpNUb).    

Is there any way to regard participant_ids as 1-93, in the order they occured, negating their true value, but using their chronological order?

Comment: Try `data$participants <- factor(data$participants, levels = unique(data$participants)`

Comment: Alright, looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/IfPXX)! Seems like it ommits the first three participatns

I received a warning:     Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_path).

Comment: Alright, I made a mistake in the ggplot command. From your original answer I changed "ggplot(aes(x = participant_id, y = proportion, color = tag )) + geom_line(lwd = 1)" to -> "ggplot(aes(x = participant_id, y = proportion, color = tag, **group = tag** )) + geom_line(lwd = 1)"

In my previous plot I had **group = 1** in the ggplot function, now resulting in [this](https://imgur.com/a/c0UtZ) pretty gorgeous plot!

Comment: Looks great! Glad you figured it out :)